# ns: _o40 malicious: (_o40 cmd line 1) invoked from within "_o40 cmd malicious" invoked from within "catch "$self cmd $args" ret"

Tags: tcl, ns2, jenkins-2

> I am simulating Wireless Sensor Network Using NS2.35 and I get an error
>   num_nodes is set 2
>       INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
>       Starting Simulation...
>       ns: _o40 malicious: 
>           (_o40 cmd line 1)
>           invoked from within
>       "_o40 cmd malicious"
>           invoked from within
>       "catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
>           invoked from within
>       "if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
>       set cls [$self info class]
>       global errorInfo
>       set savedInfo $errorInfo
>       error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
>           (procedure "_o40" line 2)
>           (SplitObject unknown line 2)
>           invoked from within
>       "*o40 malicious"
>        when i add $ns at 3.2 "[$node($id) set ragent*]malicious"get this error.
>       enter code here
>           set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;#Channel Type
>       set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation 
>       set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;
>       set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type
>       set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type
>       set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
>       set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
>       set val(ifqlen)         50                         ;# max packet in ifq
>       set val(nn)             2                          ;# number ofmobilenodes
>       set val(rp)             AODV                       ;# routing protocol
>       set val(x)      500
>       set val(y)      500
>       set ns_     [new Simulator]
>       set tracefd     [open malicious.tr w]
>       $ns_ trace-all $tracefd

```
set namtrace [open malicious.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)

set topo       [new Topography]

$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
create-god $val(nn)
set chan_1_ [new $val(chan)]
set chan_2_ [new $val(chan)]
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
        -llType $val(ll) \
        -macType $val(mac) \
        -ifqType $val(ifq) \
        -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
        -antType $val(ant) \
        -propType $val(prop) \
        -phyType $val(netif) \
        -topoInstance $topo \
        -agentTrace ON \
        -routerTrace ON \
        -macTrace ON \
        -movementTrace OFF \
        -channel $chan_1_ 

set node_(0) [$ns_ node]
set node_(1) [$ns_ node]
$ns_ at 1.0 "[$node_(1) set ragent_] malicious"
$node_(0) random-motion 0
$node_(1) random-motion 0

$node_(0) set X_ 5.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 2.0
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(1) set X_ 8.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 5.0
$node_(1) set Z_ 0.0

#
# Now produce some simple node movements
# Node_(1) starts to move towards node_(0)
#
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(1) setdest 50.0 40.0 25.0"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(0) setdest 48.0 38.0 5.0"

# Node_(1) then starts to move away from node_(0)
$ns_ at 20.0 "$node_(1) setdest 490.0 480.0 30.0" 

# Setup traffic flow between nodes
# TCP connections between node_(0) and node_(1)

set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
$tcp set class_ 2
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(0) $tcp
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $sink
$ns_ connect $tcp $sink
set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $tcp
$ns_ at 3.0 "$ftp start" 

#
# Tell nodes when the simulation ends
#
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ at 30.0 "$node_($i) reset";
}
$ns_ at 30.0 "stop"
$ns_ at 30.01 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"
proc stop {} {
    global ns_ tracefd nametrace
    $ns_ flush-trace
    close $tracefd
    exec nam malicious.nam &
    exit 0
}

puts "Starting Simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

Answer (score 0):

Your above simulation ...

```
set val(chan) Channel/WirelessChannel ;#Channel Type 
set val(prop) Propagation/TwoRayGround ;# radio-propagation 
set val(netif) Phy/WirelessPhy ; 
set val(mac) Mac/802_11 ;# MAC type 
set val(ifq) Queue/DropTail/PriQueue ;# interface queue type 
set val(ll) LL ;# link layer type 
set val(ant) Antenna/OmniAntenna ;# antenna model 
set val(ifqlen) 50 ;# max packet in ifq 
set val(nn) 2 ;# number ofmobilenodes 
set val(rp) AODV ;# routing protocol 
set val(x) 500 
set val(y) 500 

set ns_ [new Simulator] 
set tracefd [open malicious.tr w] 
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd
.
.
.
$ns_ at 1.0 "[$node_(1) set ragent_] malicious"
```

... is very close to a copy of the classic "malicious.tcl" by Xuan Chen ( See aodv-malicious-examples-04.17.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRVBTU2JOUnpKclk/view?usp=sharing )

> Xuan Chen, USC/ISI, July 21, 2000

```
# $ns_ at 0.0 "[$node_(1) set ragent_] malicious"
$ns_ at 0.0 "[$node_(1) set ragent_] hacker"
```

The error ...

> ns: _o40 malicious: 
>       (_o40 cmd line 1)

... can happen in two occasions : **1.** No "aodv-malicious" was added to your ns-2.35 . **2.** The wrong definition is used : In the most used patch, `aodv-malicious_ns235.patch` **malicious** is set as `hacker` (in aodv.cc). Which  means the setting in the simulation script must be ...

```
$ns_ at 1.0 "[$node_(1) set ragent_] hacker"
```

( Other reason for the error : You could simply be using a wrong copy of the executable 'ns' for your command `$ ns malicious.tcl` ).

---

Testing your file: `$ ns235-malicious K2-malicious.tcl` → The files malicious.nam 25.3kB, malicious.tr 15kB are created. NAM : An OK animation. "malicious.tr" : Packets are arriving → → `$ awk -f tess-Packets.awk malicious.tr` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t9aU5p0m5RxGEaLaL04pjKWHTj59fG4P/view?usp=sharing → Top 25 awk scripts.

---

`aodv-malicious_ns235.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNU0VNbUtIWlJpRk0/view?usp=sharing

All ~300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing

All ~2500 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing